# Check every word on a Website for a specific word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to check every word on the site for a specific word. But it check only the first word on the Website.

```
def wordcount(listword):
    url = f'WEBSITE'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    for word in listword:
        lower = word.lower()
        count = 0
        for sentances in soup:
            line = sentances.split(" ")
            for each in line:
                line2 = each.lower()
                line2 = line2.strip("!@#$%^&(()_+=")
                if lower == line2:
                    count += 1
                    print(count)
wordcount([WORD])
```

Comment: You don't need BeautifulSoup at all for this.  Just `print( page.content.count(word) )`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `text.count` should work for this case:

```py
import requests


def wordcount(url, listword):
    page = requests.get(url)

    return [page.text.count(w) for w in listword]


res = wordcount('https://google.com', ['abc', 'google', 'xyz'])
print(res)
# [0, 75, 0]
```

If you want word count specifically rather than just a partial search, you can try something like this:

```
import requests


def wordcount(url, listword):
    page = requests.get(url)

    wc = dict.fromkeys((w.lower() for w in listword), 0)

    for word in page.text.lower().split(' '):
        if word in wc:
            wc[word] += 1

    return wc


res = wordcount('https://google.com', ['abc', 'google', 'the', 'and', 'robots', 'videos'])
print(res)
# {'abc': 0, 'google': 1, 'the': 1, 'and': 1, 'robots': 0, 'videos': 1}
```